# Align text and flipswitch on the same line

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to align a FlipSwitch and text on the same line but no success so far. I tried using fieldContain too but no success.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
     <li><h3>Date of Birth:</h3> <span style="float:right;">
            <select name="flip-2" id="flip-2" data-role="flipswitch" data-theme="b">        
              <option value="off">Off</option>
              <option value="on">On</option>
            </select></span></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a display:inline-block on h3;

http://jsfiddle.net/q1ukjxnq/1/

CSS

```
ul li h3 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview">
     <li>
         <h3>Date of Birth:</h3> 
          <select name="flip-2" id="flip-2" data-role="flipswitch" data-theme="b">        
              <option value="off">Off</option>
              <option value="on">On</option>
          </select>
      </li>
 </ul>
```